# How to compare all the column fields of RDD (PYSPARK)

Tags: python, dataset, pyspark, rdd

Suppose that I have an rdd with just one column. I want to compare, pair after pair, the values into the one row.
ex.

```
>rdd1:
a
b
c
```

I want to store results of

```
funct(a,b),funct(a,c),funct(b,c)
```

One idea(low performant) could be:
1)rdd2=rdd1 
2)Generate Cartesian rdd1 and rdd2 and the compare each pairs
with

```
z=rddCartesian.map(lambda x: funct(x[0],x[1]))
```

But due to the fact that the dataset is huge (for example N), cartesian will have dimension (NxN), impossible to handle.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no other way than cartesian for such kind of tasks. Don't be afraid of big datasets, let spark do the job. It (generally speking) does not matter how big your middle-transformations are, but I suspect you are going to group the results after mapping `rddCartesian` so final result won't be that large?

Comment: In such a way yes, but I don't perform a truly map after cartesian, because next step is to compare the "pairs" contained in each row, for a similarity measure.

Comment: OK, so still, cartesian is the good choice.